# Cannot create temporary tables in postgres using psycopg2

Tags: mysql, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I am trying to create a temporary table in postgres. I am using psycopg2. However upon executing my python script i do not see the table being created. If i try to create a normal table, it executes without any problem. Is there any concept that i missing?My intention is to create a temp table and then import data into the temp table, do some processing and then push the temp table data into a permanent table.

Below is my code

```
import psycopg2

con = None
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='abc' user='abc' host='localhost' password='abc'")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create TEMP TABLE mytable(id int);")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

If i execute the same `create TEMP TABLE mytable(id int);` using the terminal, it creates the temp table.

Thank you @Thom Brown for your reply.

I did think of your point. To bypass the issue of con.close(), i did the following, but NO success.

```
con = None
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='abc' user='abc' host='localhost' password='abc'")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create temp table mynewtable(id int) on commit delete rows;")
cur.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
cur.execute("insert into mynewtable values(10);")
//created a new normal table from console
cur.execute("select * into dbo.test from mynewtable;")
#cur.execute("select * into test from mynewtable;")
cur.execute("commit")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Theoretically, i should be able to create the temp table using the execute command, insert some data into it, transfer all the data from the temp table to a permanent table, close the connection. The temp table datawill be lost but the permanent table should have the transferred data. This is not happening. Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

Temp tables are destroyed when the sessions ends.  When you close the connection using `con.close()` temp tables will be dropped.

If you wish to use the temp table, you will need to do it prior to closing the connection.

Comment: With your example, do you have a table named 'test', but with no data in it?

Comment: Yes, i have created a separate normal table directly using the terminal.

Comment: You're using SELECT INTO, meaning you don't need to manually create the table.  That statement will fail if you're creating it elsewhere.

Comment: Thats awesome!! Using ```select into``` to create the permanent table did the trick.However this means, i cannot create my own permanent table from the temp table, say for example with extra columns. I have to issue another query to add/alter the permanent table

Comment: If you want to insert the data into a table you've created ahead of time, you just need to use something like `INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mynewtable;` which will allow you to have additional columns in the permanent table if required.